# Creating an executable program from a Perl script

Tags: perl, strawberry-perl, par, perl-packager

I am trying to make an executable program from a finished perl script.  I installed the PAR::Packer module without difficulty. However, I do not believe I am doing this properly.  Below is the code inside the script I want to compile:

```
use PAR::Packer qw(pp);

my %pp;
% pp -o prlgap.exe prlgap.pl;
```

The above is an example I found on *Perl Monk*s. If I run the script and I get the following errors:

```
Unquoted string "prlgap" may clash with future reserved word at
C:\Strawberry\prlgap.pl line 15. Syntax error at
C:\Strawberry\prlgap.pl line 15 near "% pp -o "
```

The third line in the code is line 15. It seems strange to attempt to compile a program by running it. In my experience, this has always been done externally. What am I missing?

Comment: This looks like there is a typo. You've declared a hash `%pp` and in the next line the reference is to `% pp` (note the space). This will certainly get rid of the syntax error.

Comment: `pp` is a commandline tool that you run **on** code.

Comment: yes, pp -o ... is a command you are supposed to run.  the `%` is supposed to indicate a command prompt

Answer (score 0):

After some web searching, I found this is done externally.  Simply `pp program.pl` at the command prompt. The caveat, doing this really puts the brakes on if you have something which runs a loop rapidly. Also, the resultant executable was really large. My 65 line script compiled into an eight-megabyte program, after I removed any modules it did not need. The Strawberry installer adds environment variables which makes running a script from anywhere on a drive possible. It only requires the `.pl` extension to be added to the name. `Program.pl` for example.

Thank all of you for your replies...